# Google map api causing white screen for a split second on Chrome

Tags: android, google-chrome, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-static-api

I notice this issue is only when using Chrome on a mobile phone.

When I load a webpage that contains a google map (with api key) what happens is:
1) The page starts to load its content,
2) at some point the screen goes white (and the content disappears) for a split second and then returns and the loading continues normally.

When I use Chrome developer tools -> timing, then I notice that the white screen appears exactly when google maps scripts load.

I would like guidance as to how to prevent this from happening when loading my site using mobiles.

Additional details:

1) After loading the api I use js to place markers on the map.
2) This issue does not happen on laptops or desktops nor when using IE on mobile devices. Only with Chrome on a mobile phone.